# Why isn't my CSS working in IE?

Tags: css

I set a curve style for button and tab control.  It's working properly in Firefox, but not in IE.

Here is the CSS:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
-o-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
-webkit-border-radius: 15px; /* Experimental implementation of CSS 3 feature for webkit */
-moz-border-radius: 15px;    /* Experimental implementation of CSS 3 feature for Mozilla */
-o-border-radius: 15px;      /* Experimental implementation of CSS 3 feature for Opera */
border-radius: 15px;         /* CSS 3 feature that is not yet a recommendation */
```

You shouldn't expect to see support in it for [Internet Explorer (except version 9 beta)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28VS.85%29.aspx#border)

However, it is just cosmetic, so don't worry about it. People using Internet Explorer just don't get curved corners — it isn't a big deal, the content is still available.

Comment: thanks.. ya  i know that.. but i need to disply curves in ie too... so help me to add this in ie too...

Answer (score 0):

IE isn't able to work with that.
If you want to curve your edges in IE you'll have to use another approach.

Comment: Lots of extra elements with carefully positioned background images.

Comment: Or look for a javascript solution.
They are out there somewhere.

Comment: CurvyCorners maybe? http://www.rocketdownload.com/scripts/program/curvycorners---javascript-imageless-rounded-corners-11903.html It's the first thing which popped up when I googled for it. I bet there are loads more scripts than this one.

Comment: Seriously if you want IE to use border-radius use the link I provided. http://www.htmlremix.com/css/curved-corner-border-radius-cross-browser, This is the easiest way to do it. Or, Just go here. http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/downloads/detail?name=border-radius-demo.zip

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in IE I believe. There are some hacks to get it to work though. I've used this before and I think it good with older vs. of ie too. http://www.htmlremix.com/css/curved-corner-border-radius-cross-browser

Answer (score 0):

If you really wnt a curved corner in IE go to [Curvycorners](http://www.curvycorners.net/downloads/) & download a stable version of it. Its just a javaScript file. Then refer the "curvycorners.src.js" file from your project & write the same CSS code you are writing "-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
" except the other two properties. It will definitely work. Works for me, so for you.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to apply CSS in **IE8** or greater then it may no need to changes in CSS as you declare in **FF** but if you need to use **IE7** then you may need to use below syntax.

```
#webkit-border-radius: 15px;
#moz-border-radius: 15px;
#o-border-radius: 15px;
#border-radius: 15px;
```

Thanks.

Comment: This will cause the properties to apply **only** to browsers which (incorrectly) ignore `#` characters at the start of property names. As a result this will stop the properties applying to Webkit, Mozilla and Opera while allowing them to apply to broken versions of Internet Explorer which don't support them anyway.